# Fitch natural deduction proof of $\exists xF(x) \lor \exists xG(x) \vdash \exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm trying to create a natural deduction proof using the [openlogicproject](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) proof checker, but I just can't get it right. I have proven this on paper but I don't know how to get this right on the checker. This is what I have so far:

[image]

Can anyone please push me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you add a link to the proof checker you are using?

Comment: You need to "symmetric" sub-proofs, one for $\exists x Fx$ and the other one for $\exists x Gx$ and then conclude by $\lor$-E

Comment: Regarding the errors, you have to check the syntax for $\exists$-E

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: In general, your application of the rule to eliminate the existential quantifier is wrong, because $a$ is free in $Fa \lor Ga$. You should anticipate (and duplicate) the rule to eliminate the existential quantifier before the rule to eliminate the disjunction.

Comment: The conclusion of the $\exists$-E cannot be $Fa \lor Ga$, because we cannot have the *eigenvariable* in the conclusion of the rule. You must add $\exists$-I to conclude the sub-proof with $\exists x (Fx \lor Gx)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Sorry, we were writing the same comments at the same time.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco - no problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you apply the rule $\exists E$ to eliminate the existential quantifier in your attempt is wrong. You can see that in a twofold way.

1. *Syntactically*: The syntax of the proof checker [openlogicproject](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) requires that, when you apply the rule $\exists E$, you provide *two* arguments:

   - the line of the formula with the existential quantifier that you want to eliminate, and
   - the (starting and end) lines of the subproof you used to eliminate the existential quantifier.

   In your attempt, you provided only the first argument.
2. *Semantically*: To eliminate the existential quantifier in a formula of the form $\exists x H(x)$, you suppose $H(a)$ for some $a$ and then you have to build a subproof with conclusion $C$ where $a$ is *not free* in $C$. This is what you are missing in your attempt, from a "semantic" point of view. Indeed, the conclusion of your subproof to eliminate the existential quantifier from $\exists x F(x)$ (and similarly from $\exists x G(x)$) is $F(a) \lor G(a)$, but $a$ is free in the assumption $F(a)$ you added to eliminate the existential quantifier.

The solution to the "semantic" problem is to avoid that $a$ occurs free in the conclusion of the suproof that eliminate the existential quantifier from $\exists x F(x)$ (and similarly from $\exists x G(x)$). How to do that? You can add an existential quantifier in front of $F(a) \lor G(a)$.
You have to do it twice, once to eliminate the existential quantifier from $\exists x F(x)$, and once to eliminate the existential quantifier from $\exists x G(x)$.

So, a correct derivation in natural deduction of $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$ from $\exists x F(x) \lor \exists x G(x)$ is the following (tested with [openlogicproject](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Taroccoesbrocco! I see where I made my mistake. I knew that my justification for ∃E was incorrect but I didn't know how exactly to phrase what I meant. Appreciate it!